# Create KML "animation" / time domain from separate KML files

Tags: kml, linux, grib-2

I'm currently working on creating a weather map system with leaflet. I'm using grads to create KML files from NOAA/NCEP GFS data in grib2 format. Grads seems to be only able to write out one layer pro KML, so I end up with 60 KML files - one for each time index.

Is there any Linux command line tool which could combine those 60 KML files into one and also write the correct metadata so I could play a time domain animation of the file in Leaflet or Google Earth?

Comment: Have a look at last answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30064/how-to-merge-many-individual-kml-layers-into-one

Comment: It looks interesting, thanks. I'll tinker with it and if I find a solution, post it here.

Comment: I get 2 major problems with ogr2ogr. First is that it doesn't seem to support filled polygons. All  fill information is lost. Second, when I try to append a kml to an existing one, I get a ton of "Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point ..." and "ERROR 6: Invalid polygon". Looks like ogr2ogr doesn't like the kml output of grads very much.

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem seems not solvable. At the time of writing this, ogr2ogr / GDAL does not handle filled polys in KML correctly and grads appears to produce invalid polys in the KMLs. I therefore abandoned the idea in favor of creating PNGs for the overlays.