# no module named core

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to access and use QGIS modules/class/methods from IDLE on a mac. I have had the same problem as a few other people, and browsing the forums have tried to follow the advice they have been given.

when typing:

```
import qgis.core
```

I receive the msg:

```
ImportError: No module named core
```

I have tried to set path settings as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/share/python
```

and

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/lib
```

but I am very new to using command line for the mac and also to python.

I have now spent a couple of hours searching for others' answers that could hopefully help me, but now I am giving up and asking for advice.

Comment: Have you checked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30068/importing-qgis-core-into-python-on-osx

Comment: yes, I checked this topic and it hasn't helped - I used the different PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH that he/she uses but it makes no difference.  also - i'm using python 2.7.3 whereas he/she is on 2.3?

Comment: Can you show the content of the applicable directories? Something like "ls -l $PYTHONPATH" and "ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" may help

Comment: visit060: ls -l $PYTHONPATH
total 544
drwxr-xr-x  19 root  admin     646 20 Mar 14:23 PyQt4
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin     238 21 Feb 04:08 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  admin     374 21 Feb 04:08 qgis
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin  107468 11 Feb 20:13 sip.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   91059 11 Feb 20:13 sipconfig.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   72261 20 Mar 14:23 sipconfig.pyc
visit060:applications  ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ls: /home/applications/qgis/lib: No such file or directory

Comment: which suggests I don't have the right file (library file)  - how would i get this? ...absolutely no clue about this stuff

Comment: That suggests that LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set to the right value (you can see what it equals with something like "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH". You wanted "/Applications/QGIS.app/lib" but appear to have "/home/applications/qgis/lib". How are you setting this environment variable? Is something updating it later?