# Where is QGIS installation path in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I can't find the QGIS installation path in ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Does none of the two answers solve your problem? If one of them did please click the tick next to the answer to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 16):

A quick way to check is to type `which qgis`. It will give you the path as was stated above: `/usr/bin/qgis`

Answer (score 9):

QGIS gets installed to `/usr`.  It is launched by a shell script, `/usr/bin/qgis`.

Answer (score 5):

The location is `/usr/lib/qgis`. In there you have the 'plugins' directory, if you need to add a plugin manually.