# Why does the QgsFeatureIterator crash in my stand alone script?

Tags: pyqgis, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a standalone script in qgis 2.10 in ubuntu
I have written a script which crashes when I run from bash but works fine from inside the qgis desktop environment. The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from qgis.core import *
from platform import python_version
print python_version()
# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()

input_file = "/path/to/shape/file.shp"
input_layer = QgsVectorLayer(input_file, "input layer", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(input_layer)
print str(input_layer.featureCount())
print input_layer.dataProvider().crs().authid()
for feature in input_layer.getFeatures():
    pass
print "hello"

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

When I run from within the qgis DE I get:

```
2.7.6
105777
EPSG:2193
hello
```

When I run from bash I get:

```
2.7.6
105777
EPSG:2193
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The only thing I can guess is my interpreter choice in my shebang but none of the python executables I can find make any difference? and given the response to the version function that seems unlikely. For the shebang I also tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

with the same result.

I've seen the [docs on standalone scripts here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications)
and I figured out the correct(?) path to the installation [from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52919/where-is-qgis-installation-path-in-ubuntu) but I'm stumped as to the cause of this crash.

Comment: Not completely sure but perhaps try adding `app = QApplication([])` after your `QgsApplication.initQgis()`; and `app.exit()` after your `QgsApplication.exitQgis()`?

Comment: I think you mean:     app = QgsApplication([],False, None)     but yes that did it. If you make it an answer I'll accept it. Reading the docs on "QgsApplication" would probably be warranted for me at this point :)

Comment: I wish I meant that! But I only compared your script with several others using a linux-based system. So it's only fair that you post it as an answer (I will upvote it). Reading the manual can be useful but who has time for it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to promting by [Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) I had a look at the [docs for the application class reference](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html). In order to utilise functions from qgis in your script you need to add a qgis application class reference object.

```
 app = QgsApplication([],False, None)
```

after the

```
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

line and

```
app.exit()
```

At the end.

The docs describe the parameters but I was able to fill them as shown in order to run the script as a python shell script.

Also note that arguments for the script you write can be passed to the script from the shell as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340822/pass-bash-argument-to-python-script). I used the answer by wewa.

Also, thanks to a suggestion by Ole in [this SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119961/how-can-i-parallelise-embarrassingly-parallel-gis-operations-in-qgis-python) I can now run *any custom pyQGIS process/script/function in parallel (not just functions available within the shell as described in my answer to the above linked SE question) using the above script plus the answer here as a wrapper.

Perhaps anyone else doing the same or similar may find this useful too. My next step is to pass those parallel processes to a server(farm) and speed my custom scripts up even more.

Comment: Note also the changes to newer versions of QGIS which are resolved at the end of the bug discussion https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13494