# How to run qgis scripts in parallel across remote server(s)

Tags: qgis, parallel-processing, bash

I have a stand alone python script using qgis that I wrote with the help of the [SE question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153210/why-does-the-qgsfeatureiterator-crash-in-my-stand-alone-script)

The script takes three arguments being; an input file path, an output file path, and another input file path. a la:

```
myscript.py input1.shp output.shp input2.shp
```

As per advice from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119961/how-can-i-parallelise-embarrassingly-parallel-gis-operations-in-qgis-python) the script now happily runs in parallel using [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and gives the correct output files with the following command:

```
parallel myscript.py {.}.shp {.}_output.shp /tmp/input.shp  :::  /tmp/tile_{1..443}.shp
```

I want to do the work in parallel on a remote server (or servers). So I enabled a passwordless login to an available server as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login), I installed QGIS on the remote server, copied over the script, and made it executable from bash. If I manually copy the required input files over to the server the same parallel command as above runs fine.

The problem I have is when trying to run the remote parallel work from the local machine.

There is an example for running a remote process described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Distributing-work-to-local-and-remote-computers)

One could imagine that the equivilent gis type line as per my example might look as follows:

```
parallel --trc {.}_output.shp -bf /tmp/input.shp -S 192.168.88.222,: \
'myscript.py {.}.shp {.}_output.shp /tmp/input.shp'  :::  /tmp/tile_{1..443}.shp
```

Unfortunately, there's a fundamental problem with this approach. If a GIS program calls the path to a "shapefile" as an argument; while `/path/to/my/file.shp` will work most of the time, the "shapefile" actually consists of a collection of files with a common filename prefix. When run, the program actually locates whichever file it needs from the collection from the path to the ".shp" file.

This issue then becomes a problem when the gis script is operating in the remote environment since it doesn't have access to the full collection of files.

The question is then how do we solve this?

Comment: An important distinction for remote parallel GIS scripts in comparison to the example at ['Distributing work to local and remote computers'](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Distributing-work-to-local-and-remote-computers) is the fact that a .shp file has a number of associate files that qgis will need as well as the actual .shp file. These could be gzipped first but how to do it for only the remote hosts?

Comment: --basefile /tmp/input.shp --bf /tmp/input2.shp --bf /tmp/input3.shp

Comment: As per [shape file collections - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) an example of a shape file collection might be `/tmp/input.shp` and `/tmp/input.shx` and `/tmp/input.dbf` but could include a number of others such as `/tmp/input.prj`

Comment: @OleTange Can we have 12 (or more) basefiles? and can we use replacement strings in the basefile designations?

Comment: there is no limit for basefiles. They are transferred before the first job, so you cannot use replacement strings in the basefile designations.

Comment: there is no limit for basefiles. They are transferred before the first job, so you cannot use replacement strings in the basefile designations.  It can also be a dir, but then the cleanup does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more conventional (and simpler) cluster computing solution is to have a shared directory in the master node mounted in each slave node and let the networking protocols handle all the file passing. [As per this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1ka8mn/transient_beowulf_clustering_with_gnu_parallel/)

Rather than building a network folder mounting script I just did it all manually using nfs. First, install nfs on the master and create the shared folder

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
mkdir -p /home/richard/netshare
```

Then, set up a permanent tmpfs folder in order to make access to the master data as fast as possible. Add the following line to the end of `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs /home/<user>/netshare tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

Replace `<user>` with a user which exists in each node.
This creates a tmpfs drive half the size of your RAM and has very fast access for the rest of your network.

Next mount the tmpfs drive as an nfs share as per [SettingUpNFSHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo). Add the following line to `etc/exports`

```
/home/<user>/netshare       192.168.88.0/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

Again where `<user>` is a user on each system and `192.168.88.0/24` is your local network. (in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)).

Now restart your nfs server.

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Setup the slave nodes

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
mkdir -p /home/<user>/netshare
```

Then when you want your slave node to have access to the shared directory you can run the following line on the slave node

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.88.239:/ /home/<user>/netshare
```

where 192.168.88.239 is the ip address of the master node

If you dont want to have to manually mount the shared directory you could try something like the sshfs script described in the first link or you could try [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs). Neither of which worked for me however. Or you could modify the sshfs script to mount nfs drives as described here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `--return` takes an argument: GNU Parallel can guess which file to transfer, because it assumes you give the files to transfer as argument. But it cannot guess which file to return, as you could be creating all sorts of files. In your case the file to return is probably:

```
/tmp/output_{1}.shp
```

so:

```
--return  /tmp/output_{1}.shp
```

But maybe you want the input and output file removed on the remote server, too?

```
--transfer --return /tmp/output_{1}.shp --cleanup
```

which can be shortened to:

```
--trc /tmp/output_{1}.shp
```

Comment: Thanks, thats not the only problem though. The --transfer appears to take the parallel {1} argument as its argument and fails to find the "./1" "./2" etc files so I need to rrewrite to correct that. But As per my own comment the main problem with remote parallel gis is the fact that most operations require the path to the .shp file as an argument but then use the associated files as well... Let me edit and update the question to reflect the real issue for remote parallel GIS using gnu-parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution which should work for most any stand alone qgis script; It solves the "shape file collection" problem by wrapping the call to the qgis script with tar pipes as follows:

```
(parallel 'touch {.}.tar && rm {.}.tar && tar -cf {.}.tar {.}.* && echo {.}.tar' ::: tile_{1..445}.shp)|\
(parallel --bf input.tar --trc {.}_out.tar -S $SERVER1,: 'tarwrap.sh myscript.py {.}.tar {.}_output.tar input.tar')
(parallel 'tar -xf {.}_out.tar && rm {.}_out.tar && rm {.}.tar' ::: tile_{1..445}.shp)
```

I know it looks horrific but let me break it down:
The first parenthetic portion uses parallel locally to `tar` the shapefile collections into single files (first deleting any existing tar files of the same name) and then echos the resultant list of tar files as the argument to the second parenthetic portion.

The second parenthetic portion uses gnu-parallel to carry out the qgis script on the remote servers and in a sence mirrors the non-working example remote use of parallel given in the question. Note especially here the addition of the "tarwrap" function and the exchange of the script's shape file arguments for tar file arguments. Now, since the arguments represent single files the gnu-parallel program will work as desired to pass the shape file collections to the remote servers.

Finally the third parenthetic portion (which is a seperate command) untars the result and deletes the temporary tars from the local PC

The purpose of the tarwrap.sh bash script is to build a clean temporary folder in each of the remote servers and untar the shape file collections into them, then run the qgis script with its shape arguments as required - changing the "tar" arguments back to there respective "shp" arguments as required. Finally the tarwrap.sh script retars ALL the shape files back up and delivers them to the gnu-parallel working directory for return and cleanup.

The code for the tarwrap.sh script is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpdir=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
mkdir /tmp/$tmpdir
execstring=""
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ "${var: -4}" == ".tar" ]
    then
    B=$(basename "$var"); D=$(dirname "$var");
    subvar="$D/${B%.*}.shp" #change the command 'tar's to 'shp's
    execstring="${execstring}$subvar " 
    if [ -f "$var" ]
    then
        tar -xf "$var" -C "/tmp/$tmpdir" #untar the supplied shp files
    fi
    else
    execstring="${execstring}$var "
    fi
done
runscript=${execstring::-1}
(cd "/tmp/$tmpdir" && $runscript) #Execute the supplied command with shp instead of tar
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ "${var: -4}" == ".tar" ]
    then
    cwd=$(pwd)
    godir="/tmp/$tmpdir"
    inshp="${var::-4}"
    cd $godir
    for fname in $(ls | grep $inshp); do tar -uf "${inshp}.tar" "$fname"; done
    cd $cwd
    mv "$godir/$var" "$cwd/$var"
    fi
done
rm -r "/tmp/$tmpdir"
```

This is tested and now working for me to run my qgis scripts across multiple remote hosts.

Points to note:
both your python qgis script and the tarwrap.sh script need to be accessible from the parallel working directory of your remote servers AND executable from there.

Have a good look at how your "expected" remote parallel command for the qgis script as exemplified in the question translates into the three part wrapped command in this answer.

Finally please note that this process should work for *any qgis script. You just need to remember to replace the shp arguments with tar arguments and let the tarwrap.sh script handle untaring and retarring the results. Any other arguments to your qgis script can be left as is.

Comment: The good thing here is that the tar pipes are not computationally intensive and serve only to simply concat the files. tar was in fact made exactly for this job so it does it well and fast.