# QGIS layer tree API returns only groups and not layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to use the QGIS python API to read out the groups and layers in a QGIS (2.4) project. Here is a code snippet from my script, which is run from a shell, not from the QGIS python console!

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import *

proj=QgsProject.instance()
proj.read(QFileInfo("/var/qgis-projects/testproject.qgs"))

print "QGis version:"+QGis.QGIS_VERSION
print "Project title: "+proj.title()
print "Project tree root children:"
root=proj.layerTreeRoot()
for node in root.children():
    print "- "+node.name()+" ("+str(type(node))+")"
```

It prints the following when I run it:

```
QGis version:2.4.0-Chugiak
Project title: This is my project title
Project tree root children:
- Field Data (<class 'qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup'>)
- Aerial Photos (<class 'qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup'>)
- Other Maps (<class 'qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup'>)
- Model Results (<class 'qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup'>)
```

Only `QgsLayerTreeGroup` objects are returned but no layers (`QgsLayerTreeLayer` objects), even though I also have two layers in the project root. When I open the python console in QGIS while I have my project open and run:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
[<qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup object at 0xa3f9170>, <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup object at 0xa3f9200>, <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup object at 0xa3f9290>, <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeGroup object at 0xa3f9320>, <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeLayer object at 0xa3fe320>, <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeLayer object at 0xa3fe830>]
```

This does return the `QgsLayerTreeLayer` objects for my layers that I'm after. How come there is a difference?

Edit: I'm trying to run my python script from a shell, not from the QGIS python console.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out I did not properly initialize QGis like you're supposed to when writing standalone scripts. Adding the following lines made everything work:

```
QgsApplication([], True) #a path was not needed
QgsApplication.initQgis()

#do all the things with your QgsProject here

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/how-to-write-standalone-python-scripts-using-qgis) and the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications) got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

look at Martin Dobias's [QGIS Layer Tree API (Part 1)](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo # no need of from qgis.core import * in the console)
root=proj.layerTreeRoot()
proj.read(QFileInfo("/var/qgis-projects/testproject.qgs"))
root=proj.layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
         print "- group: " ,child.name()
    elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
         print "-layer: ", child.layerName()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I meant to say I'm trying to run my script from a shell, not from the QGIS console. I think I understand how the code works (I found Martin's posts as well) but for some reason in my case ``root.children()`` only returns ``QgsLayerTreeGroup`` objects and no ``QgsLayerTreeLayer`` objects, even though I clearly also have layers in my project.

Comment: No problem for me from the shell. What is your QGIS version ?