# QGIS: Script is being executed successfully in Python console (within QGIS) but not in a standalone python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have the following code which I have no problem executing within QGIS (2.8.6) via the python console. What the script does is it adds the two raster layers in my directory via the Raster Calculator:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

from gdalconst import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import * 
from qgis.gui import *
import sys
import glob
import re 
import os, fnmatch
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import math 
import subprocess 

qgisprefix = '/usr'

# configure paths for QGIS 
os.environ['PATH'] = qgisprefix+'/bin'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = qgisprefix+'/lib'
sys.path.insert(0, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python')
sys.path.insert(1, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python/plugins')

# disable QGIS debug messages
os.environ['QGIS_DEBUG'] = '-1'

# configure QGIS paths
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgisprefix, True)

# initalise QGIS (load providers)
QgsApplication.initQgis()


#Load all the rasters  
outputFolder = "/home/usr/Desktop/Output/"
extent = QgsRectangle(264885.85754, 5073773.01243, 614325.85754, 5295173.01243)
numCols = 11648
numRows = 7380

os.chdir("/home/usr/Desktop/")
entries = []

for fname in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(fname) 
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName() 
    rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer(fname, baseName)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rasterLayer) 
    mc = iface.mapCanvas()
    Layers = mc.layers()
    for each_layer in Layers:
        layerR = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        layerR.ref = each_layer.name() + '@1'
        layerR.raster = each_layer 
        layerR.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(layerR) 

expression = '('+entries[1].ref+'+'+entries[0].ref+')' #re-write that to include all rasters 
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, "/home/usr/Desktop/Output/final.tif",'GTiff',extent,numCols,numRows,entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

When I try to execute the same code outside QGIS in a standalone script, I get no errors but there is nothing in my `Output` folder. What should I adapt in order to be able to run the script outside of QGIS?

Comment: Have a look at this answer from @underdark: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/how-to-write-standalone-python-scripts-using-qgis

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not include this part of my code, but it is in the python script just as indicated in the link you attached. Unfortunately, there is no output

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

`app = QgsApplication([],False, None)` before `QgsApplication.initQgis()` in your script:

```
# configure QGIS paths
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgisprefix, True)

# initalise QGIS (load providers)
app = QgsApplication([],False, None)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

and end the script with:

```
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
app.exit()
```